# Weird VC++ Intellisense Behavior

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, intellisense

Intellisense is broken with this code, everything is undefined to Intellisense from tree header:

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <list>
```

But when I move my own bst implementation header file down a bit, Intellisense starts working again.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "tree.h"
```

Why is this?

Comment: IntelliSense is fragile, and is the reason tools like Visual Assist-X are popular.

Comment: 1) IntelliSense with C++ is really fragile
2) You might have some declarations in "tree.h" that interfere with declarations in the standard headers.